# What anime or manga is this pink-haired girl in an athletic outfit from?

Tags: merchandise

[image]

I need help finding who this character is, and what anime or manga she is from. It came from a Burger King kids meal around 7 years ago.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

It's looks like [Mariah Wong](http://beyblade.wikia.com/wiki/Mariah_Wong) from Beyblade
(金李, Japanese: Chou Mao, Chinese Pinyin: Wīng Maou)
[image]

Comment: @kawaiipugachan The pleasure is my, friend.
And welcome to Anime & Manga.
If you find this answer satisfying, Please choose it as the right answer